# Computing the inverse of $I - \lambda E$ where $E^{k+1} = 0 $ for some $k \geq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $E$ is a square matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ with $E^{k+1} = 0$ for some $k \geq 1$, then show that $I - \lambda E$ is invertible for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ by explicitly computing its inverse. What can you deduce about $E$'s eigenvalues?

I'm not really sure what the inverse of this matrix would be, or how to work it out. I think that $E$ must be singular, since:

$$ E^{k+1} = 0 \implies (\det E)^{k+1} = 0 \implies \det E = 0$$

But then what does that tell me about $I - \lambda E$?

I've tried a few things that look like they might work, like:

$$ I + E + E^2 + \ldots + E^k$$

Which gives:

$$\require{cancel} (I - \lambda E)(I + E + \ldots + E^k) = I - \lambda E + E - \lambda E^2 + \ldots + E^k - \cancel{\lambda E^{k+1}}$$
$$ = I + (1-\lambda) E + (1-\lambda)E^2 + \ldots + (1-\lambda)E^k$$

And so that looks like the inverse for $\lambda = 1$, but how can I find the inverse for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$?

Presumably, the second part of the question will be clear once I've done the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I-(\lambda E)^{k+1}=I\\
\implies (I-\lambda E)(I+\lambda E+(\lambda E)^{2}+\cdots+(\lambda E)^{k})=I$$

So the inverse of $(I-\lambda E)$ is $(I+\lambda E+(\lambda E)^{2}+\cdots+(\lambda E)^{k})$.

As for the second part remember that eigenvalues are roots of minimal polynomial and minimal polynomial divides any annihilating polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Set $A=I+\lambda E+\lambda^2 E^2+...+\lambda^k E^k$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
(I-\lambda E)A&=&(I-\lambda E)(I+\lambda E+\lambda^2 E^2+...+\lambda^k E^k)\\
&=&I+\lambda E+\lambda^2 E^2+...+\lambda^k E^k-\lambda E-\lambda^2E^2-...-\lambda^{k}E^k-\lambda^{k+1}E^{k+1}\\
&=&I-\lambda^{k+1}E^{k+1}\\
&=&I
\end{eqnarray}